# why Floating point exception?

Tags: c++

I have a floating point exception, and I don't know why.

the code is this:

```
void calcola_fitness(){
    vector<double> fitness;
    int n=nodes.size();
    int e=edges.size();
    int dim=feasibility.size();
    int feas=(feasibility[dim-1])*100;
    int narchi=numarchicoll[dim-1]/e;
    int numero_nodi=freePathNode.size()/n;
    double dist_start_goal=node_dist(0,1);
    int i,f,t;
    double pathlenght=0;
    int siize=freePathNode.size();
    for(i=0;i!=siize-1; i++){
        f=freePathNode[i].getIndex();
        i++;
        t=freePathNode[i].getIndex();
        i--;
        pathlenght=pathlenght+node_dist(f,t);
    }        
    double pathlenghtnorm=pathlenght/10*dist_start_goal;
    double fit=((double)numero_nodi+pathlenghtnorm+(double)narchi)*((double)feas);
    fitness.push_back(fit);
}
```

Could anybody help me? What's the problem? I could I solve this?
thank you very much

Comment: On what line do you get the error? What is the value of `dist_start_goal`?

Comment: It compile, but in execution when I ask this method, I have that error.
the method node_dist is this:

double node_dist(int from, int to){
return nodes[from].distance(nodes[to]);
}

Comment: You can't get a SIGFPE from returning a number.

Comment: You have 'lenght' consistently where 'length' is conventional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Floating point exception" (SIGFPE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGFPE) is actually a misnomer. Any kinds of arithmetics exception will trigger SIGFPE. This includes divide-by-zero.

You should check if `nodes` and `edges` are empty.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest thing you can do is using a debugger to capture the exact place where the exception is being thrown. If you are using g++ you can use gdb and make it stop in the throw:

```
shell$ gdb binary
(gdb) catch throw
(gdb) run
```

Chances are that any of the divisors in the code is 0 and that is triggering the exception, but using a debugger will tell you the exact line and you can check the variable values.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have the following:

```
int siize=freePathNode.size();
for(i=0;i!=siize-1; i++){
    f=freePathNode[i].getIndex();
    i++;
    t=freePathNode[i].getIndex();
    i--;
    pathlenght=pathlenght+node_dist(f,t);
}
```

Lets assume freePathNode.size() returns 2.  On the first iteration, f will be the index of element [0], and t will be the index of element [1].  That's fine.
On the next iteration, f will be the index of element [1], and t will be the index of element [2], which does not exist.

So as a guess, that's where the error is coming in... you're doing a getIndex() of the end() iterator.

Comment: If `freePathNode.size()` returns 2 then that loop will only go through one iteration. Although if it returns 0 it will loop through the whole range of `int`, when it shouldn't loop at all.